# Setting a directory and adding other folders inside of that directory(.bat file)

Tags: windows, batch-file, executable

I need help setting a directory in batch, and then adding other folders inside of that directory, but any code I try doesnt work. The file is named "a.bat" in this case, and it needs to make a directory named "a". Then it needs to make "1", "2", and "3" inside of the "a" directory(1, 2, and 3 being folders). This is my code. Whenever I run it, it just makes 4 different directories inside of the directory that I ran a.bat in.

```
@echo off
MD a
Set adir = C:\a
cd %adir%
MD 1
MD 2
MD 3
```

If anyone knows what I did wrong, I'd appreciate it if you could help. Thanks!

Comment: Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty; in which case `var` becomes *undefined*) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. In this case `adir` is not being `set`, "adir<kbd>Space</kbd>" is being set, hence `adir` has no value and `cd %adir%` becomes `cd`.

Comment: It still didn't work. I am unsure why, maybe because I am using MD instead of something else.

Comment: `a` will be created in the current directory. You need to remove the spaces around the `=` in the `set` command in order to set `adir` correctly. For preference, use `set "adir=C:\a"`. Now this specifically sets `c:\a` into `adir`, so `cd %adir%` will switch the directory `C:\a`, not subdirectory `a` from the current directory. For that, you need `set "adir=%cd%\a"` - `%cd%` being a magic variable that is resolved as the **C**urrent **D**irectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something in your question, what's wrong with:

```sh
MD "C:\a\1" "C:\a\2" "C:\a\3"
```

You could follow that up, *if you wish*, with `CD /D "C:\a"`.

Full example:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "adir=C:\a"
MD "%adir%\1" "%adir%\2" "%adir%\3"
CD /D "%adir%"
```

Comment: Just had to edit it a little, but it worked! Thanks. Here's the code now:
`@echo off
MD a
Set "adir=a"
MD "%adir%\1" "%adir%\2" "%adir%\3"`

Comment: There was no need to edit anything, `MD "%adir%\1" "%adir%\2" "%adir%\3"` will also create `C:\a`, when it creates its subdirectories. That's why I did it like this, my code required no editing, except for the user definable location in between the doublequotes on line `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Magoo said: Batch is sensitive to spaces in SET.

That's why use following syntax:

```
set "var=value"
```

without spaces.

Also you change your directory to %a%, but %adir% would be defined

do

```
set "adir=C:\a"
cd %adir%
```

instead

(also important: you create the folder "a" at "C:" and not your working directory)

Comment: Actually, the variable "adir[SPACE]" is defined. And defined as having the value "[Space]C:\a".  The spaces on **both** sides of the `=` are included in the assignment. Both should be removed - and preferably the syntax `set "adir=C:\a"` should be used to prevent any trailing spaces on the `set` command-line being included in the value assigned.

Comment: Should I edit the answer in that case? I am kinda new to Stack. Or are you gonna edit my answer?

Comment: Sure - edit the answer. Makes more sense if you add a notation in the edited answer that it has been edited in response to comments, otherwise the comments seem rather odd.